# Process is not working properly

Tags: c#, string, process, formatting

I can able to execute the same command in the command prompt, but when I try to execute using c# process.start() it is not working, Below is used code

```
string localCommand = String.Format("{0} {1} \"{2}\"",
"\"" + path + "\"", @"-licp", Lie);

Process Process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo pStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
pStartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
pStartInfo.Arguments = localCommand;
pStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
pStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.StartInfo = pStartInfo;
Process.Start();
Process.WaitForExit();
Process.Close();
```

Below is the output of the above code

`"C:\\Program Files\\xx\\xx\\xx.exe"` -lic "xx"

`"C:\\Program Files\\xx\\xx\\xx.exe"` from process.start() but when I append the next parameter it is not working.

Below is the working code

```
string localCommand = String.Format("{0} \"{1}\" {2} \"{3}\" \"{4}\"" ,
@"-lic", lie, "-xx",      "xx", xx);

Process Process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo pStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
pStartInfo.FileName = "\"" + Path + "\"";
pStartInfo.Arguments = localCommand;
pStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
pStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.StartInfo = pStartInfo;
Process.Start();
Process.WaitForExit();
Process.Close();
```

Comment: Sort of strange to use CMD to just run exe... Can't you do it directly?

Comment: you mean without cmd? then what can I give as filename? directly the executable?

Comment: var p = new Process {StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {"filename"}}; Replace "filename" with the executable path

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".